# Road Symbol/Label issues in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, attribute-table

I am trying to control how many road symbols and how do I do that ? I have geodatabase that has Transportation and in it has a featureclass, "Major_Rds" and it also has three symbology for Interstate, NM state roads, and US roads.

What I would like to do is to limit a few symbols to be display at a specific scale.

[image]

You can see there are too many road symbols in Southeast New Mexico but you see a few in Northwest Texas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Nathanus's answer will work at any ArcGIS license level.

If you have a Maplex license, you can specify that duplicate labels should be removed only *if they fall within a certain distance*.

[image]

You can also repeat the markers at specified intervals:

[image]

This can be useful for aiding map readability (eg in your example, marker 62 might be shown both below and above highway 285)

Comment: Stephen Thanks! After I post my questions, I began to do what you were suggesting and it worked!  There are several lists to choose from and I choose points and it is the only one that works. I wonder why there are several are on the list to choose from?

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you. I'm not sure what you mean about several lists to choose from - can you provide further details? The Maplex dialogs that I showed are found under the layer's > Properties > Labelling tab. You need to set Maplex as the map labelling engine first (on the map's Labelling toolbar). Let me know if you need a hand with that

Comment: Ok, when you hit the Limits button and it brings up Duplicate Labels dialog box. It ask you to choose the search radius and then you have choose Map Units, Inches, Points and Centimeters. So my questions so why are there 4 to choose from ? and what are the difference the 4 ?

Comment: **Map Units** will be feet, meters, miles etc (whatever you've set the map's units to be in the Properties dialog). The other options (Inches, Points and Centimeters) refer to **Page Units**, for example 5 inches on the printed map

Answer (score 4):

Under the `Labels` tab of the Layer Properties, there is a `Placement Properties...` button. Inside there you can set various options to control how labels display. Make sure under Duplicate Labels you have selected the option to `Remove Duplicate Labels`. Also, you may consider converting your labels to annotation so that you can delete and realign them more conveniently.

Another option, if you wish to have more scale-based label visibility is to create duplicate layers that are only visible at certain scales using the `General` tab's Scale Range options.

Just a few ideas.